# problem in scan with HP Scanjet G3110 scanner

Tags: scanner, debian

I am very Amateur in linux

I have a HP Scanjet G3110 scanner that installed in my Debain 10 .
after i do scan with that 
my picture color is very bad .

my picture after scan:

[scan in Debian 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAr9O.png)

But my scanner is very good in windows .
please help me .

Comment: Do those lines appear when you scan at a lower resolution? According to the [SANE project supported devices page](http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html#Z-HEWLETT-PACKARD) the HP Scanjet G3110 is not fully supported. What is the output of `scanimage -L`?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani   scanimage -L show in terminal  'device `hp3900:libusb:004:009' is a Hewlett-Packard Scanjet G3110 flatbed scanner'

Comment: That's the right one. If you are not doing that already, you could try to scan with `xsane`. You can then adjust many parameters, to get the best possible image. Check the images they show in the [project's page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hp3900-series/) to see what to expect. Lower resolutions might work better.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani check very parameters in xsane  but don't work right